# How to calculate it? :$|V_p|(1∠0^\circ-1∠-120^\circ)=\sqrt{3}|V_p|∠30^\circ$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I saw this math formula in the circuit system. It said 
$$|V_p|(1∠0^\circ-1∠-120^\circ)=\sqrt{3}|V_p|∠30^\circ$$

Does anyone know how to calculate $|V_p|(1∠0^\circ-1∠-120^\circ)$ to $\sqrt{3}|V_p|∠30^\circ$ ?

Example of the notation: 
$$6∠60^\circ=(6 \cos 60^\circ)+j(6 \sin 60^\circ)$$

Comment: If I understand correctly, don't you just plugin each of angles into its imaginary-sine and cosine (and then combine the real and imaginary parts respectively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add them
$$1\angle0°=1\cos0°+j1\sin0°=1+j0$$
$$1\angle-120°=1\cos-120°+j1\sin-120°=-\frac12-j\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
$$1\angle0-1\angle-120°=\frac32+j\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
If we isolated the $\sqrt3$, we have
$$\sqrt3\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+j\frac12\right)=\sqrt3\left(\cos30°+j\sin30°\right)=\sqrt3\angle30°$$